# Get Value Using Three Criteria Across Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook full of schedules. Each schedule is its own sheet. I want a formula that will tell me who was working on a particular day, a particular location, in a particular position.

I've been using this

```
INDEX('01'!$A$1:$I$1000,MATCH(1,('01'!$A$1:$A$1000=$A$2)*('01'!$B$1:$B$1000=B2),0),MATCH(C1,'01'!$C$1:$F$1,0))
```

and it's not giving me the right result.

On the schedule, column A is the Location, column B is the position, and row 1 is the date.

Dashboard

[image]

Schedule

[image]

Would anybody be able to help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you enter the formula and what result did you need?